# In what physical contexts do the Airy2 process or the Tracy-Widom distribution arise?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

I'm currently writing a Master's thesis in mathematics on the Airy$_2$ process, and have read vague references that it comes up in statistical mechanics when dealing with large systems of an ideal Bose gas (my search for a paper on this has thus far been unsuccessful, however). Moreover, general random matrix theory, which this is very closely linked to, is said to be very frequently encountered in statistical physics.

I'd like to include some references in the thesis and maybe even see what my results would be in the context, so what I'm interested in would be papers on GUE or GOE random matrices, the Tracy-Widom distribution, and especially the Airy$_2$ process, and their meaning in a physical context.

Comment: You could look, for instance, at the references given in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0701021). Most of the applications mentioned are in a physical context (mostly statistical mechanics). (I realize that there is a positive probability that you wrote your thesis under the author's guidance; if that's the case, he would be a good source for additional applications to physics ;) ).

Comment: Another paper with several links to applications, written by physicists, would be [this one](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.96.060101). There are of course many others.

Comment: @YvanVelenik You are indeed right, Prof. Ferrari is my advisor. Not to mention that I have taken a seminar based on your book last semester - the world is indeed small, it appears. Also, the second link is extremely helpful, thank you!